# Multi type user authentication in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to develop a multi-vendor e-commerce backend. It has 4 types of users.

1. Customer
2. vendor
3. staff
4. admin

If I use a collection model and user_type to handle 4types of users then a staff/vendor will not able to register as a customer.
If I use different collection models for different types of users then there will be too many routes. I need to develop login, register, update, getOne, getAll routes for each type of user.

So, which is the best way to design a collection for multi-type users and  manage routes in efficient way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage in same collection like email with user_type, if email already registered as staff or vender(user_type like staff/vendor) restrict user to register as a customer. You can easily manage using email with user_type check.